# Inactive window makes messes with timing

Tags: javascript, game-development

This is a strange one to explain. I have a particle system where every frame I create a new particle until there is a certain number of them. This creates a streak like effect as seen here:
[image]

The problem I am experiencing is that when I change to a different window and come back to my page, it appears as if all those particles where made at the same time, causing instead of a streak, just dots to appear :
[image]

The code for particle creation and recycle here :

```
Update(felapsed){
this.AddParticle();

let vec = GetVectorFromAngle(this.Player.Rigidbody.Orien);
vec.Mult(-1 * 50);

for (let i = 0; i < this.Particles.length; i++){
  let item = this.Particles[i];

  item.DrawRes.Opacity = Lerp(0,1,item.Lifetime);
  item.Lifetime -= felapsed;

  if (item.Lifetime < 0){item.Restart(this.Rigidbody.Pos, copyInstance(vec));}

}
```

The Add Particle function here :

```
if (this.ParticleCount < this.ParticleLimit){
  let p = new this.ParticleType();
  this.Particles.push(p);
  Game.AddObject(p);
  this.ParticleCount++;
}
```

and finally the Particle.Restart function :

```
this.Lifetime = this.Life;
this.Rigidbody.Pos = locate;
this.Rigidbody.Vel.Mult(0);
this.Rigidbody.Vel = vel;
```

I suspect I am doing something dumb but just oblivious to it, any tips?

Comment: Is it your own game engine or a library? If you suspect an inactive window makes a difference you can at least add some debugging with [window.onfocus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onfocus) and [window.onblur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur). I suspect your `felapsed` to go 0 or something. Suspending and resuming your game also needs to be debugged for closing and reopening a laptop for example, so not a waste of time to just `console.log` your way to victory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am using my own engine and I checked felapsed when the window is inactive and it accumulates until the window is active again. that said, I did not know about window.onfocus and window.onblur functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. When the browser is inactive or a different tab is active, the frame time increases overtime above the normal expected result until the game tab is active. This means that all my particles would be dead and restart in the same frame, hence they become in sync.

The fix I chose is very patchy and will be done better but at the beginning of every frame, I check felapsed to ensure its not gone above the normal expected time (0.6) and if it does, just set felapsed to 0 for that frame.

Essentially, I paused the game when the browser is not active :)